# How to test postgresql credentials from bash?

Tags: django, bash, postgresql, testing, psycopg2

I have a Django application that runs from a virtual environment. I am writing a bash script to test the virtual environment.
The postgresql username and password are environment variables in the virtual environment, that Django pulls into `settings.py`.

In order to test the connection to the database, I have written the following:

```
echo -n 'Testing database connection  ...'

export COMMAND="from psycopg2 import connect; import sys; c=connect(dbname='myappdb',\ 
user='$POSTGRESQL_USER', password='$POSTGRESQL_PWD', host='127.0.0.1', port=5432); \
sys.exit(c.closed)"

test `python -c "$COMMAND" 2>/dev/null && echo true `
```

Where test is a function:

```
function test {
  [ $1 ] && echo "[OK]" || echo "[FAIL]"
}
```

It seems that even with the wrong credentials, no exception is raised and `c.closed` is always zero. Is there a way I can test if the credentials are right in the virtual environment?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's bash, not python, so not sure if it fits you needs:

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql -d "postgresql://p:goodpassword@localhost/t" -c "select now()"
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-07-14 11:42:40.712981+03
(1 row)

vao@vao-X102BA:~$ echo $?
0
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql -d "postgresql://p:badpassword@localhost/t" -c "select now()"
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "p"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "p"
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ echo $?
2
```

If you want to suppres output, instead of `select now()`, you can just quit with `-c "\q"`

Comment: The `pg_hba.conf` was showing `trust` everywhere. Works like a charm now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do you not have `psql` on your machine? It'd be more simple to use a command app than python to do what you want.

```
if PGHOST=127.0.0.1 PGPORT=5432 PGUSER=$POSTGRESQL_USER PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRESQL_PWD \
        PGDATABASE=myappdb psql -c \q 2>/dev/null
then
    echo "[OK]"
else
    echo "[FAIL]"
fi
```

`PGHOST=127.0.0.1 ...` is temporarily exporting variables to `psql`.
 The `\q` just tells the client to quit immediately if the connection was successful.

Comment: Found out that `pg_hba.conf` was configured with `trust`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `pg_hba.conf` file that was in use was:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I changed it to:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

and both answers above work.